# add .scss support to create-react-app v1.1.1 app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

How do I add support for `.scss` file in my `create-react-app` application? 
The current [method](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-a-css-preprocessor-sass-less-etc), described in the documentation, creates a `.css` files and I have to import that to make it work. What I require is to import `.scss` directly into the components. 

There are several guides on doing this using webpack config files. But I don't have a `config` folder in my `create-react-app` or any `webpack-config.dev.js`. 
Is there a simpler way to do so?

Comment: The `.css` file you are importing in your components (after you add support for `.scss`) is already precompiled from your scss file. Not sure why do you need to explicitly import the `.scss` file?

Comment: You actually don't need to import any .css file. You can simply create a `main.scss` file, and import all partials into your root div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run eject to have your webpack.config.

Try this [link](https://medium.com/@Connorelsea/using-sass-with-create-react-app-7125d6913760).